# Pairwise connected (not fully connected) layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I would like to create a network in which I have 8 inputs, connected in pairs to 4 nodes in the hidden layer, and these are completely connected to 3 outputs ([Network image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw15C.png))

I made this code but I'm not really sure if it represents what I would like. could you tell me if it's ok or advise me how to change it?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
X_train = np.loadtxt('input.txt')
y_train = np.loadtxt('output.txt')
data = keras.layers.Input(shape=(8,))
node1 = keras.layers.Dense(2)(data[:,0:2])
node2 = keras.layers.Dense(2)(data[:,2:4])
node3 = keras.layers.Dense(2)(data[:,4:6])
node4 = keras.layers.Dense(2)(data[:,6:8])
hidden = keras.layers.concatenate([node1, node2, node3, node4])
output = keras.layers.Dense(3)(hidden)
model = keras.models.Model(data, output)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1000, batch_size=1)
```

My inputs are numbers in the range 1-10 and the outputs in the range 0-1. I have a small dataset so I set `batch = 1` to use all of them for each cycle.

With `model.summary()` I expected 3 lines, or 6 (dividing the 4 hidden nodes) instead I see 11 and this makes me doubt.
Using `model.layers[i].weights`, for i 0 to 4 and also 9 = [], why?; i from 5 to 8 there are 2 weights but bias is always 0, why?; while i = 10 gives 12 weights and 3 biases as i would expect for the last layer.

Also, is there a way to visualize with an image what is being done with tensorflow?

Finally, a conceptual question, does making a single network (8-4-3) like the one described or training 3 different networks with a single output (8-4-1) lead to differences in accuracy?

Answer (score 1):

```
node1 = keras.layers.Dense(2)(data[:,0:2])
node2 = keras.layers.Dense(2)(data[:,2:4])
node3 = keras.layers.Dense(2)(data[:,4:6])
node4 = keras.layers.Dense(2)(data[:,6:8])
hidden = keras.layers.concatenate([node1, node2, node3, node4])
```

This is different from the image you posted.

In the [image you posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw15C.png), the network has 4 neurons in the second layer. In the model.summary() output, the output of the concatenate layer is (None, 8), meaning it's the output of 8 neurons.

The fix is to change 2 to 1.

Alternately, you can use [LocallyConnected1D](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LocallyConnected1D), which is a built-in layer which can do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This  is a correct implementation (apart from Dense(2) leading to you
having extra hidden units, it should be Dense(1)). If you do summary you will see

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)           [(None, 8)]          0           []                               
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.getitem (Slic  (None, 2)           0           ['input_1[0][0]']                
 ingOpLambda)                                                                                     
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.getitem_1 (Sl  (None, 2)           0           ['input_1[0][0]']                
 icingOpLambda)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.getitem_2 (Sl  (None, 2)           0           ['input_1[0][0]']                
 icingOpLambda)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.getitem_3 (Sl  (None, 2)           0           ['input_1[0][0]']                
 icingOpLambda)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)                  (None, 2)            6           ['tf.__operators__.getitem[0][0]'
                                                                 ]                                
                                                                                                  
 dense_1 (Dense)                (None, 2)            6           ['tf.__operators__.getitem_1[0][0
                                                                 ]']                              
                                                                                                  
 dense_2 (Dense)                (None, 2)            6           ['tf.__operators__.getitem_2[0][0
                                                                 ]']                              
                                                                                                  
 dense_3 (Dense)                (None, 2)            6           ['tf.__operators__.getitem_3[0][0
                                                                 ]']                              
                                                                                                  
 concatenate (Concatenate)      (None, 8)            0           ['dense[0][0]',                  
                                                                  'dense_1[0][0]',                
                                                                  'dense_2[0][0]',                
                                                                  'dense_3[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 dense_4 (Dense)                (None, 3)            27          ['concatenate[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 51
Trainable params: 51
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

The reason why youy see 11 elements is because you have:

- 1 input node
- 4 "input grouping nodes" (those are responsible for extracting pairs of features)
- 4 hideen nodes
- 1 concatenation node
- 1 output node

The "input grouping nodes" are created because of `data[:, 0:2]` like pieces of code. They of course have no weights, they are just data transformation operation (and thus when you look at weights you do not see any there)

> Also, is there a way to visualize with an image what is being done with tensorflow? it would be very useful.

You can use [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/graphs) for that.

> Finally, a conceptual question, does making a single network (8-4-3) like the one described or training 3 different networks with a single output (8-4-1) lead to differences in accuracy?

These are very different. The main difference boils down to whether information about different targets can benefit from **shared representation** of the data (then 8-4-3 would be better) or not (8-4-1). Importantly also with 3x (8-4-1) you will probably get better results just because you have more weights. A "fair" comparison would train a wider joint model, so 3x (8*4+4 + 4*1+1) ~= 100 weights, while 8*4+4+4*3+3 ~= 40. 8-8-3 would be roughly of similar size then.